# c# Textbox ReadOnly Property sometimes work, sometimes does not work

Tags: c#, properties, textbox, readonly

I would like to consult you something which is very very uncommon in Visual Studio 2015. I have been preparing a Windows Form Application. In that application, I placed a textbox on a Form and set its ReadOnly property to True. Then, I started the Application. At first, textbox did not accept any letters or numbers because of ReadOnly property, but after some time it started to accept letters and numbers despite of its ReadOnly property.

Then, I changed the textbox with a new one, but it did again the same thing after some time. I cannot understand this stuation and why I faced such an interesting problem. Have any of you guys faced with a similar problem before and I would like to know how you solved it.

Comment: `after some time` This is not very accurate. Add some steps to reproduce the exact behaviour.

Comment: Can you provide the code around the text box, e.g., anywhere the ReadOnly property is referenced, its setup/creation from the Designer file, etc.? This will give us a better idea of what's there and what maybe going on. Do you have any Timers active that might be changing the property, etc?

Comment: `after some time` may be you are changing its readonly property programmatically

Comment: Search for `ReadOnly` in your codebase and check whether some code is altering that property at runtime.

Comment: @mjwills I checked everywhere in the code, but there is no use it. When I add a new textbox, it works very well, but this one does not work for ReadOnly property. By the way if I delete the textbox and add another text with the same name, the problem still continues. I cannot understand this issue. I will update my VS for the last chance

Answer (score 0):

Never seen this before, but what you can do to debug it, is to add a handler to the TextBox.ReadOnlyChanged event. Something like this:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    roBox.ReadOnlyChanged += roBox_ReadOnlyChanged;
}

private void roBox_ReadOnlyChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    throw new Exception("who did this");
}
```

And then put a breakpoint on that Exception. Whenever that property gets changed to true, it will break and land you on that breakpoint. Then you can investigate from Call stack, which bugger is modifying th read-only flag.

Answer (score 0):

Any possible that you load the `Form` again in your code. Just thinking this because you set `ReadOnly` property after `InitializeComponent()`. Reloading the `Form` and setting the `property` again might cause the problem. Any way, this is just wild guess.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Weissu , but the problem still is still going on. You won't believe that I have 3 other textboxes and they have the same ReadOnly property, but while those 3 textboxes are working great. The other one always makes me crazy and accept letters. Maybe I should change its name completely

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution
I cleared temp files by typing %temp% in Run (Windows+R) and everything comes back to normal, now its ReadOnly property